# Adding attributes to a generated SVG file

Tags: javascript, svg, gruntjs

In my project i am using grunt to generate an svg sprite sheet based on individual svg files/graphics. For this i am using the grunt contribution called 'grunt-svg-sprite'.

My first question would be: Is it possible to add attributes (such as an ID or the preserveAspectRation attributes) to the root element of this generated sprite? does grunt-svg-sprite ship with an option to do something like this? Reading the docs did not help me.

Alternatively i have tried to add a task to my gruntfile using grunt-execute. This task would be run immediately after the svg sprite has been generated. The idea was to call an external javascript to insert the attribute, something along the lines of:

*Gruntfile.js*

```
execute: {
        target: {
            src: ['svgsprite_script.js']
        }
    }
```

*svgsprite_script.js*

```
var root = document.documentElement;
root.setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio', 'none');
```

Should i somehow specify which file to modify? Above code throws an error about 'document' not being defined.

What is the best way, if there is a way, to add attributes to a generated svg file? Or more precisely: How do i add the 'perserveAspectRatio' attribute to an svg sprite generated with 'grunt-svg-sprite'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cheerio to load your svgsprite file. It gives you a jquery like interface to your document which you can use to change the document in many ways... including adding IDs

https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio